# High non-invariance when using the Alignment method

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mplus, invariance

I am attempting to use the Alignment within CFA method from Marsh et al. (2017) on 2015 PISA. However, six out of the nine factors have more than 25% non-invariance. What can be done to a dataset that is found to be mostly non-invariant using the alignment method? Does this mean than the 6 factors can not be compared across countries? Or are there other procedures I can use?

Comment: Hi BtO, welcome to CrossValidated. Can you provide more information? What is Marsh, et al, 2015. What is PISA?

Comment: Thank you. PISA (Program for International Student Assessment) is an international survey sent to students that asks students about many topics, however I am interested in the nine items asking about ICT (Information and Communication Technology). Marsh et al. (2017) is a publication that details the Alignment within CFA method for the first time. The title of this publication is "What to do when scalar invariance fails: The extended alignment method for multi-group factor analysis comparison of latent means across many groups."